# Python str.format with string contatenation and continuation

Tags: python, string, format, concatenation, continuation

I'd like to specify a string with both line continuation and catenation characters. this is really useful if I'm echoing a bunch of related values. Here is a simple example with only two parameters:

```
temp = "here is\n"\
    +"\t{}\n"\
    +"\t{}".format("foo","bar")
print(temp)
```

here's what I get:

```
here is
    {}
    foo
```

And here is what I expect:

```
here is
    foo
    bar
```

What gives?

Answer (score 4):

You can try something like this :

```
temp = ("here is\n"
        "\t{}\n"
        "\t{}".format("foo","bar"))
print(temp)
```

Or like :

```
# the \t have been replaced with
# 4 spaces just as an example
temp = '''here is
    {}
    {}'''.format

print(temp('foo', 'bar'))
```

vs. what you have:

```
a = "here is\n"
b = "\t{}\n"
c = "\t{}".format("foo","bar")
print( a + b + c)
```

Comment: Your second solution will have 2 additional "\n", you need to remove the 2 typed "\n".

Comment: For your second code block, you'll have to use ```temp = '''\``` to make the whitespace consistent.

Answer (score 3):

`str.format` is called before your strings are concatenated. Think of it like `1 + 2 * 3`, where the multiplication is evaluated before the addition.

Just wrap the whole string in parentheses to indicate that you want the strings concatenated before calling `str.format`:

```
temp = ("here is\n"
      + "\t{}\n"
      + "\t{}").format("foo","bar")
```

Comment: Just remove the `+` concatenation, and leave it to the compiler to concatenate the literals.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I'll take the performance hit if it means clearer code. Implicit string concatenation has caused me more than enough problems.

Answer (score 2):

Python in effect sees this:

```
Concatenate the result of
    "here is\n"
with the resuslt of
    "\t{}\n"
with the result of
    "\t{}".format("foo","bar")
```

You have 3 separate string literals, and only the last one has the `str.format()` method applied.

Note that the Python interpreter is concatenating the strings *at runtime*.

You should instead use *implicit string literal concatenation*. Whenever you place two string literals side by side in an expression *with no other operators in between*, you get a single string:

```
"This is a single" " long string, even though there are separate literals"
```

This is stored with the bytecode as a single constant:

```
>>> compile('"This is a single" " long string, even though there are separate literals"', '', 'single').co_consts
('This is a single long string, even though there are separate literals', None)
>>> compile('"This is two separate" + " strings added together later"', '', 'single').co_consts
('This is two separate', ' strings added together later', None)
```

From the [*String literal concatenation* documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation):

> Multiple adjacent string or bytes literals (delimited by whitespace), possibly using different quoting conventions, are allowed, and their meaning is the same as their concatenation. Thus, `"hello" 'world'` is equivalent to `"helloworld"`.

When you use implicit string literal concatenation, any `.format()` call at the end is applied to that *whole, single string*.

Next, you don't want to use `\` backslash line continuation. Use parentheses instead, it is cleaner:

```
temp = (
    "here is\n"
    "\t{}\n"
    "\t{}".format("foo","bar"))
```

This is called [*implicit line joining*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#implicit-line-joining).

You might also want to learn about *multiline* string literals, where you use three quotes at the start and end. Newlines are allowed in such strings and remain part of the value:

```
temp = """\
here is
\t{}
\t{}""".format("foo","bar")
```

I used a `\` backslash after the opening `"""` to escape the first newline.

Answer (score 1):

The format function is only being applied to the last string.

```
temp = "here is\n"\
    +"\t{}\n"\
    +"\t{}".format("foo","bar")
```

Is doing this:

```
temp = "here is\n" + "\t{}\n"\ + "\t{}".format("foo","bar")
```

The key is that the `.format()` function is only happening to the last string:

```
"\t{}".format("foo","bar")
```

You can obtain the desired result using parentheses:

```
temp = ("here is\n"\
    +"\t{}\n"\
    +"\t{}").format("foo","bar")
print(temp)

#here is
#   foo
#   bar
```